# output form values to xml using php for loop

Tags: php, html, xml

So I'm having trouble setting up a for loop in PHP to output the contents of an HTML form to an xml file. It works without the for loop, but not with. Any ideas? Tearing my hair out!

Thanks in advance.

```
//PHP Form

<?php
if (isset($_POST['lsr-submit']))
{
}
$str = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><entrys></entrys>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);
$i=1;
for ($i=1; $i <50; $i++) 
{ 
   $name = $_POST['Name_'.$i];
   $time = $_POST['Time_'.$i];
   $duration = $_POST['Duration_'.$i];
   $name = htmlentities($name, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false);
   $time = htmlentities($time, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false);
   $duration = htmlentities($duration, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8', false);
   $xml->Slot = "";
   $xml->Slot->addChild('Name', $name);
   $xml->Slot->addChild('Time', $time);
   $xml->Slot->addChild('Duration', $duration);
}
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->loadXML($xml->asXML(), LIBXML_NOBLANKS);
$doc->save('../scSHARE/editor.xml');
print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\"     content=\"0;URL=return.php\">";
?>

//HTML Form

<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("../scSHARE/editor.xml");
$xml_array = (array) $xml;
$chunks=array_chunk($xml_array["Slot"], 7);
$i=1;
$l=1;
foreach($chunks as $bank) {
  ?> 
  <form name="form1" method="post" action="form.php">
     <div class="menu-toggle bank_<?php echo $i; ?>"  style="display:none;">
       <?php
       foreach($bank as $slot) { ?>
         <div class="row">
           <div class="small-12 column">
             <div class="small-6 column">
                Slot <?php echo $l?>
               <input type="text" name="Name_<?php echo $l;?>" value="<?php echo $slot->Name;?>">
             </div>
             <div class="small-6 column">
               <div class="row">
                 <div class="small-6 column">
                  Time
                   <input type="text" name="Time_<?php echo $l;?>" value="<?php echo $slot->Time;?>">
                 </div>
                 <div class="small-6 column">
                   Duration
                   <input type="text" name="Duration_<?php echo $l;?>" value="<?php echo $slot->Duration;?>">
                 </div>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       <?php $l++;} ?>
      <p style="text-align: center;">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="hollow success button" value="Update">
      </p>
     </div>
  </form>

<?php $i++;
}
?>
```

Comment: First of all, your `if (isset($_POST['lsr-submit']))` has no effects. You need to apply it to all your code, not to nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You use this syntax:

```
for ($i=1; $i <50; $i++) 
{ 
    (...)
    $xml->Slot = "";
    $xml->Slot->addChild('Name', $name);
}
```

By this way, at each iteration you override previous `<Slot>` node. You have to add child(s) to root node instead:

```
for ($i=1; $i <3; $i++) 
{ 
    (...)
    $slot = $xml->addChild( "Slot" );
    $slot->addChild( 'Name', $name );
    $slot->addChild( 'Time', $time );
    $slot->addChild( 'Duration', $duration );
}
```

---

*Side note:*

Consider wrapping entire code by `isset($_POST['lsr-submit'])`

```
if (isset($_POST['lsr-submit']))
{
    $str = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><entrys></entrys>';
    (...)
    print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\"     content=\"0;URL=return.php\">";
}
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, its working perfectly now. Thanks for the quick response. Much appreciated!